# Conditional trigger on a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, conditional-statements

I am unable to create a simple conditional trigger to insert data to a new table. Below is the trigger and its output:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[test_trigger] 
ON [dbo].[Export_Data]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test (Terminal_ID, EmpIdentification, SwipeDateTime) 
        SELECT  
            DeviceId, UserId, LogDate 
        FROM 
            Inserted
END
```

OUTPUT is as follows:

[image]

My requirement is that I need logs of only Terminal_ID = 32 & 33 only.

Thank you

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code factory and we are not free services.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @satish-g, please accept the answer if it helped you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a where clause to the select statement from the `Inserted` table. If you're inserting `Export_Data.DeviceId` into `test.Terminal_ID`, then your filter should be `where Inserted.DeviceId in (32,33)`:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[test_trigger] on [dbo].[Export_Data]
for insert
as
begin
    insert into test(Terminal_ID,EmpIdentification,SwipeDateTime) 
    select DeviceId,UserId,LogDate from Inserted
    WHERE DeviceId in (32, 33)
end
```

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks a ton. Your comment has helped me.

Comment: Hi Max, I have one more query. I want to push data from one server to another using Task Scheduler and by sqlcmd. Here is the argument i use for sqlcmd.exe :-  -S "Server IP,Port No\SQLSERVER" -U username -P password -d database -Q "exec data_export"     .  The server where i want to push uses a custom port. Please guide me as i am able to export using data_export procedure manually. But i want to do it automatically using Task Scheduler.

Comment: Kindly help to resolve it.

Comment: Post that as a new question. It doesn't have anything to do with the original question, and the new post will help people who have a similar question in the future.